# select the most recent date among relative duplicates

Tags: postgresql, date, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table "installation" and a table "controle". For one installation, there may be several controls with a different date of control *(field : controle.des_date_control)*. So several controls may have the same installation_id.

```
 ════════════╤════════════╤══════════════ 
  id_install │ id_control │ date_control
 ════════════╪════════════╪══════════════ 
  9001       │ 194        │ 1905-07-03    
 ────────────┼────────────┼────────────── 
  9001       │ 193        │ 1900-01-01    
 ════════════╧════════════╧══════════════
```

I want to keep the line with id_control = 194

Now, what I want to do is to create un view which lists the most recent control for each installation : I did this, putting **max** in front of the field "des_date_control" :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW s_anc.v_anc_test AS 
   SELECT installation.id_installation,
   controle.id_controle,
   controle.des_date_installation,
   max(controle.des_date_control),
   controle.des_interval_control,
   controle.cl_date_prochain_control,
   controle.cl_classe_cbf
FROM 
   s_anc.installation,
   s_anc.controle
WHERE upper(installation.archivage::text) = 'FALSE'::text 
   AND controle.cl_classe_cbf = 'Absence de défaut'::text 
   AND (controle.des_date_installation < '2014-01-01'::date OR controle.des_date_installation IS NULL) 
   AND installation.id_installation = controle.id_installation
GROUP BY installation.id_installation,
   controle.id_controle,
   controle.des_date_installation,
   controle.des_interval_control,
   controle.cl_date_prochain_control,
   controle.cl_classe_cbf;
```

But the view eventually lists all of the controls, not only the most recents...

Can you help me ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: You should try to remove columns of controle table from select which have one or more values for installation_id. That will fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks a_horse_with_no_name, i did it.

Comment: Thanks @GauravS, it works : I let "id_installation" and "des_date_control" in the SELECT.

Comment: Please up vote comment if it helped you.

Comment: I can't vote up for my own question :-/